# Apple Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, background, multitasking

I'm building an app that checks as site every 15 minutes for changes. I can do this fine in the app, when it's open. But how do I go about doing this while the app is in the background?

The trouble is I don't think I can use the Push Notification Service. The page on the site which is being checked, requires the user to be logged into the site. Because there is a cookie jar for each app, the user logs into the site through a UIWebView at the beginning and then once logged in, the site is polled every 15 minutes using NSURLConnection and receives the data for the logged in user because of the cookies created at login in the webview. I don't believe there is a way to do this on a server for many different users? And if there was wouldn't the user's site username and password have to be stored on my push server which is a huge no.

So can I use task completion, or is it possible to access a page that only appears correct when the correct cookies are present from a server and then use push notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to get the cookie from a UIWebview. And task background completion can only run for 10 minutes.

I'm not sure what kind of website you are trying to access, but if you can replicate the login using a NSURLConnection you can retrieve the cookie using NSHTTPCookie. Then store the cookie data on your server and then access the web site from the server with the "Set-Cookie" header to check the content for changes.

This, of course, depends on how long the cookie lasts (expires).

Comment: Is ok to store cookies on a server, could someone hack peoples account from that. Also how would the server know whos cookie is whos?

Comment: Well, you should warn your users that you will be doing that. And of course, if someone got access to the server he could hack accounts. You need to make sure your server setup is secure as possible.

Comment: You can tie the user cookie to the users push notification token.

Comment: @tomislav, thanks, I'm not sure what you mean about Set-Cookie, I thought that was a response header, not a request header?

Comment: Yes, "Set-Cookie" sent by the web server, the browser sends "Cookie". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation

Comment: @tomislav, so if I have to get the cookies, upload them to the server, secure them etc, associate the cookies with the user's push notification token, then poll the site for each user setting the "Cookie" HTTP header field.